# Firefox 50.1 : Secure Connection Failed

Tags: firefox, https

For some reason Firefox is no longer loading the URL https://www.google.com/. When attempting to do so, the following message is displayed

> **Secure Connection Failed**
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> - Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

This problem doesn't happen when attempting to load other websites. https://www.youtube.com/ loads without a problem.

**Relevant information: (Updated 1)**

- <s>The system has Kaspersky Internet Security 17 installed (with scan encrypted connections upon request from protection components enabled)</s>
- <s>The system has Kaspersky Secure Connection installed but not used.</s>
- The problem occurs in Firefox 50.1 (desktop), Internet Explorer but not in Google Chrome.
- The problem occurred in an android device's Firefox browser.
- The problem occurred in a friend's pc who lives in the same country (Egypt)
- The problem only occurs when using Google NCR. Not Google Eg.
- The problem does not occur when using google chrome.

**Solution Attempts**

- Kaspersky Internet Security => Network Settings => Encrypted connections scanning : now uses the option "Do not scan encrypted connections" instead of "Scan encrypted connections upon request from protection components enabled"
- Deleted Firefox profile's cert8.db while Firefox was closed
- Cleared all Firefox history (with all options ticked)
- Shutdown Kaspersky Internet Security and Kaspersky Secure Connection and made sure that the process were closed via Process Explorer
- Disabled Kaspersky Firefox plugin
- All of the above together.

None of the attempts worked.

I tried reading some similar questions. some of them were to complex for me, the others were not the same case/cause.

**My Questions**

- <s>How to solve the problem and be able to use encrypted google search?</s>
- How to troubleshoot encrypted connection problems generally?

**Update 2**
Problem was **NOT a system/machine-local**. And Whatever caused this problem does not exist anymore. **problem solved**.

Comment: Most likely your clocks time is off.

Comment: System clock were not changed between the two states of it working and not working. And System clock seems to be accurate.

Comment: Tried problematic URL on other browser within same PC and antivirus working normally?

Comment: updated question.

Comment: +1 for well written question. It may never have the answer that would have helped you then; it may never have the proper explanation of what happened. Still it may be useful for anyone encountering the same phenomenon. This person will know such things may have an external cause.

Answer (score 1):

Add the **.eg** top-level domain.

This only happens only with Firefox, but not Chrome because Chrome redirects it automatically.  Egypt is trying to throttle Google services in order to abandon "Signal" communications because Signal is now routing its traffic through Google's CDNs.

[image: Google.com]

[image: Google.com.eg]