# How to disable «Secure Connection Failed» for all visited sites?

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate, firefox-extensions, ssl-certificate

**UPD**: Problem was reproduced for me in Windows 10 EN Enterprise LTSB 64-bit. I install Windows → I download browsers (more I do not download anything after installation) → I get same errors.

---

### 1. Problem

For example, I visited **https://bower.io/** site. Instead of site content I see `Secure Connection Failed`:

[image: SCF]

When I visited a lot of sites, I see `Secure Connection Failed`. How I can disable it **always, for all visited sites**?

I detect these problem about half-year — almost at the same time as I bought a mew computer. The vast majority of sites open normally for me, but for some sites I get `Secure Connection Failed`.

I don't think, that bower.io or another sites banned in Russia — my country.

---

### 2. Environment

1. Windows 10 x32,
2. Firefox 50.0.1,
3. I'm not use antiviruses or others anti-malware applications,
4. I'm disable Windows Firewall and others Windows security tools.
5. I'm not use proxy.

[image: No proxy]

---

### 3. Not helped

1. The problem reproduced for me in Firefox Safe Mode.
2. I check my computer on viruses, use [**HerdProtect**](http://www.herdprotect.com/). I have not malware in my computer.
3. I can not visited **https://bower.io/** via *Internet Explorer 11.576.14393.0* and *Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m*:

[image: Bower Explorer]

[image: Bower Chrome]
4. [**I change values**](https://superuser.com/a/938564/572069) for `security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha` and `security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha` in Firefox configuration.
5. I delete `cert8.db` file into my profile, but if I run Firefox again, `cert8.db` was created for me again.
6. I add [**.eg top-level domain**](https://superuser.com/a/1161127/572069), to bower.io, but that site still not open for me.
7. I [**update internet time**](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6410-clock-synchronize-internet-time-server-windows-10-a.html):

[image: Internet time]

---

### 4. Do not offer

1. **Please, don't tell me, that my computer is more vulnerably, I reduce my security and so on**. I understand it, but I do not matter want to disable `Secure Connection Failed`.
2. Please, do not offer solutions, how I can set **my** sites, that no get `Secure Connection Failed`. I'm not owner of the sites, which I visited.
3. Please, do not offer solutions, how to [**disable for each site separately**](https://superuser.com/a/916880/572069). I don't want wasting my time to add an exception for each site, I want solution for all sites at once.
4. Please, do not offer to use [**Browsec VPN**](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/browsec/?src=ss) or other VPN addons. I use Browsec VPN in my Firefox, and that visited **https://bower.io/**, I need enable Browsec VPN → visited bower.io → disable Browsec VPN, because, it works slowly. I want to visited bower.io in «normal mode», without proxy or VPN.

Comment: Did you try to see **why** the certificates aren't trusted? (No idea how you do that in Firefox though.) Maybe your system or some proxy is compromised already?

Comment: @Mario, not, I don't understand, how I can do it. I don't use proxy by default and every week I check my computer use [**HerdProtect**](http://www.herdprotect.com/). What else should I do? Thanks.

Comment: If you can open the sites with a proxy or VPN, then it's a Deep Packet Inspection (DPI) or your country has restricted connecting to those sites using port 443 (HTTPS port).

Comment: Your system thinks something is wrong with these certificates, but for everyone else they are OK. That indicates a problem with your system. You should fix that problem, not hide its symptoms.

Comment: Please include translations of browser warnings on screenshots that you've added.

Comment: @gronostaj, [**OK**](http://superuser.com/posts/1164406/revisions). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Reasons can be many. I would like to suggest few

- Check that you are under proxy by navigating to
  [about:preferences#advanced](http://about:preferences#advanced), Open Connection Settings. Example settings preview: 
  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrpkZ.jpg)
- Check the application that you're running. If you are running from a 
  shortcut then the shortcut could be edited and running a malware app
  then that app is running firefox with some modified settings. Try running firefox from the {original installed location}/firefox.exe
- If the shortcut's target url contains different path or contains any arguments to firefox then there's a malware installed in your browser. Check the installed addons/extensions. Uninstall untrusted addons.

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: Arifuzzaman Pranto, your answer not helped for me, see [**question update**](http://superuser.com/posts/1164406/revisions). Thanks for answer!